# Redirect www to naked domain using CloudFlare

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cloudflare

I would like all my requests to www.example.com to be redirect to example.com, in order to ease anaylitics and for marketing reasons. I could not find out how to this this with CloudFlare (I was used to doing that in Namecheap's Redirect records)

Comment: You'd typically do it on the server, not via DNS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess I just solved the problem. I added a CNAME for the www subdomain plus a PageRule to forward requests made to it.

Comment: PageRule won't work without a CNAME

Comment: Mind sharing your code?

Answer (score 2):

This is the redirection page rule that worked for me.

```
*www.qforex.ml/* --> https://qforex.ml/$2
```

The number after `$` will represent the nth occurrence of `*`.

The image below shows the details.

[image: Cloudflare URL Forwarding]